# Elasticsearch 5.x as nosql data store

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I currently have a website with mongodb as nosql data store and elasticsearch powering the search function. The data is more or less duplicated from mongodb to elasticsearch. I have to update the search code as it is still runing on a very old version of elasticsearch.

In the process I discovered that elasticsearch in its latest iteration is already much closer to an nosql data store then before.

From a feature perspective:

- My data is mainly read, few updates
- The data has documents with subdocuments
- I use geo indexes in mongo, I would like to add geo information to elasticsearch in future

Does anyone have a current version of Elasticsearch as nosql data store in production? I only found very outdated information covering elasticsearch version 1.5 and before. From the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html) I see that a lot of the issues have been fixed in 2.0 and 5.0.

Can anyone with insight and experience with version 5.x give some recommendation?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a rather broad question and I would vote to close it, except I've been wondering the exact same thing and look forward to reading responses!

Comment: @RobertMoskal true, how could we make it more specific? My main question is can I replace mongoDB for rather simple usecases with elasticsearch as nosql data store.